# MacOS Terminal says my template uses pdftex, but I set it up with xetex. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

```
MacOS 12.2
TexShop v.4.68
```

**At the top of my template:**

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

**In the preamble, among other things:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

**TeXShop Typeset console states:**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021)
 (preloaded format=xetex)
```

Using this template in pandoc, **Terminal states:**

```
> Error producing PDF. ! Fatal Package fontspec Error:  The fontspec
> package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. You must change your
> typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of
> "latex" or "pdflatex".
>l.45 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

Line 45 of my template:

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{$background-image$}%
```

**Selected xelatex** as the engine, but Typeset console still says it is XeTeX.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You should have `% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX`

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the “magic line” is to declare the engine and format to use for processing the file *independently* on the engine chosen in the drop-down menu for typesetting, that is, the equivalent to ⌘-T.

So you should have

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
```

The error message you get from `pandoc` seems to hint to the fact that the engine it chooses is `pdflatex`, but you give no information about how you run `pandoc`.

Comment: **New “magic line”: % !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX**;

**pandoc command:**

>pandoc 1Letter.docx -f docx -t pdf -->template=/Users/<william>/.local/share/pandoc/templates/modified->text.tex -o >11Letter.pdf

**result:** same error as above: 

> Error producing PDF. ! Fatal Package fontspec Error:  The fontspec
> package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX …

Comment: @william I don't think that `pandoc` knows about those magic lines; you have to tell it to use XeLaTeX in some way. I believe you need the option `--pdf-engine=xelatex` or `-t xelatex` instead of `-t pdf`

Comment: Thanks, I keep working on this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `% !TeX` comment is simply a comment, the default behaviour is that it is ignored. Some editors may read it to choose a program to run but that is not specified by tex, it is a feature of the editor.

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options

indicates that you can use `pandoc -t xelatex`  to tell pandoc to use xelatex rather than pdflatex.

Comment: **removed the %; and, used -t xelatex in the command:** 

**result:**

>pandoc 1Letter.docx -f docx -t xelatex -->template=/Users/<william>/.local/share/pandoc/templates/modified->text.tex -o >11Letter.pdf

>cannot produce pdf output from xelatex

Comment: sorry I don't have pandoc installed I can't help muxh with pandoc, but someone can probably help. Basically this has answered the question you asked here, pandoc is now using xelatex (even if giving errors) @william

Comment: Thanks, I keep working on this.